# $e^z=3z^5$ - Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, roots

> **Question :** Show that the equation $e^z=3z^5$ possesses five distinct
>   real roots.

In using the Rouche's theorem with the function $f(z)=-e^z+3z^5$ and $g(z)=-3z^5$, I succeeded to prove the first part. How could I prove that the five solutions are **distincts**?

My teacher explain : Consider that $z_0 \in D(0;1)$ be of multiplicity $\geq 2$. So we must have $$f(z_0)=e^{z_0}-3z_0^5=0$$ and $$f'(z_0)=e^{z_0}-15z_0^4=0$$ that imply $z_0=5$. Impossible.

Is anyone could explain what the teacher explain?

Comment: you mean real roots only?

Comment: your equation in real numbers can have mostly two roots (i didn't look to small details). But you can solve it by using the Lambert W function. You can read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1. If you Google it, you can see its graph and notice there are two branches of this function, hence mostly two real roots.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the notation $D(0;1)$. I am going to interpret it as $z_0$ is one of the root with multiplicity 2, which should exists if the solutions are not distinct.

Hence $z_0$ should satisfy both $f(z_0)=0$ and $f'(z_0)=0$.
$$f(z_0)=e^{z_0}-3z_0^5=0 $$
$$f'(z_0)=e^{z_0}-15z_0^4=0$$

subtracting the equations gives us 
$$15z_0^4-3z_0^5=0$$

Since $f(0)=1 \neq 0$, $z_0 \neq 0$. Hence, dividing by $z_0$, we obtain $15-3z_0=0$ and we can conclude that $z_0=5$.

but let's check substitute $z_0=5$ into $e^{z_0}-3z_0^5$ and check if it is indeed a root.

$$e^5-3(5)^5 < (3)^5-3(5)^5=3(3^4-5^5)<0$$

Hence $z_0=5$ is not a root, which is a contradiction. Our assumption that a root with multiplicity 2 exists must be wrong. The roots have to be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Assume by contradiction that one of the roots $z_0$ is not simple.
This means that 
$$f(z)=(z-z_0)^2g(z)$$
for some $g$ which is analytic at $z_0$.

Then 
$$f(z_0)=0 \\
f'(z_0)=2(z_0-z_0)g(z_0)+(z_0-z_0)^2g'(z_0)=0$$

This gives $15z_0^4-3z_0^5=0$.

Therefore $z_0=0$, which is not possible, or $z_0=5$ which doesn't lie in $D(0,1)$.